# Eager loading, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have an album class and two classes linked to it, genre and artist. I use eager loading to load the album objects and the linked entities:

```
var albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Artist).Include(a => a.Genre);
```

After loading, I try to access the properties of the linked entities from an album object in the dataset, but the navigation properties are null

```
Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
var name = album.Genre.Name;
```

`name` is null.

My question is, after the eager loading, do the objects loaded in the album dataset contain the references to the linked entities "artist" and "genre"?

I don't want to activate lazy loading.

Thanks

Comment: `db.Albums.Find()` executes a separate query. Use `Album album = albums.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);`. Then, you can access `album.Genre`.

Comment: Is this the same instance of `db`? Once they are in the change tracker, they should be linked.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Only when the `albums` query is actually loaded into memory (which is not the case here). Calling `albums.ToList()` or `albums.Load()` should do the trick.

Comment: Right.. missed that albums was still an IQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

When Lazy Loading is **enabled**, the navigation property (linked entity or collection of entities) gets automatically loaded when you access it for the first time. That's why `album.Genre` would work fine as long as the DbContext is not yet disposed or if the `Genre` property (of a certain Album) has been accessed before.

When Lazy Loading is **disabled**, you don't have that flexibility. You need to eagerly (or explicitly) load the linked entities. You are off to the right start by using `Include()` (Eagerly Loading). However, since `albums` is not yet materialized (not loaded into memory), attempting to access the `Genre` property by executing a *different* query (which is what `db.Albums.Find()` does) will fail.

You have two options here...

#### Materialize the query:

```
var albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Artist).Include(a => a.Genre).ToList();
Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
// Works because all `Album.Genre` **of all `Album` records** is loaded into the EF cache.
var name = album.Genre.Name;
```

#### Find the target Album using the *same query* that includes linked entities:

```
var albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Artist).Include(a => a.Genre)
// This will force EF to load the "included" entities for this one specific record.
Album album = albums.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
var name = album.Genre.Name;
```